# how can i detect if a page on safari was opened from the springboard?

Tags: javascript, iphone, detection, iphone-standalone-web-app

i saw it once and i cant find it again:

how to detect via JavaScript if an iphone webapp was opened from a url typing or from an icon in the springboard?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can detect if a page has been opened in full screen mode.

```
if (window.navigator.standalone) {
  //
} else {
  //
}
```

Pages launched from home screen icons with the following meta tag will open in full screen mode.

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

Comment: thanks, damn that's no good:-\
my app cant run on full screen because its a search engine full of outside links...

bahh